# error: /'boot' not found

Tags: live-usb, kde-neon

I have downloaded KDE Neon, a few days ago. I tried to install it using live usb, but it would not install completely, having trouble at grub installing.

I tried twice, but got some results.
Today I have downloaded it again, but now I'm facing another problem that is:

> After BIOS it prompting
> error: /'boot'/ not found

after that

> error: invalid magic number
> alloc magic is broken at 0x602c7280:6014dd40 (this address changing on each boot)
> Aborted: Press any key to exit

after exit

> ISOLINUX 6.03 20171017 FHDD Copyright(c) 1994 - 2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
>
> Failed to load idlinux.c32
> Boot failed: Press any key to retry...

and all this looping.
I've checked UEFI boot is enabled or not but, that's not fixing it.
I'm using
Intel Pentium© Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz × 2
But it's not a matter of configuration. So please, what is the cause of all that.
Getting **error: /'boot' not found** in first place is may cause of that.

Comment: Did you check the check-sum of the downloaded file? Torrent is a good tool for downloading big files. It can re-start, and it will self-check.

Comment: check the `sha256sum`, they have a file with it in (it is a very small file).

Comment: Is that their sha256sum (from the sha256sum file), or the one you calculated? You need to compare the two.

Comment: On Debian and many other Unixs, there is a program called sha256sum. run as `sha256sum «file-to-calculate-sha256sum-of»` (What OS are you using?)

Comment: It will have the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sha256sum is different, then it is a different file. It is practically impossible for two files to have the same sha256sum (there is not enough time and files in the universe for this to happen), and logically impossible for a file to have two sha256sums.

Therefore the files are different. This is probably a download error.

Comment: But I had changed url and that doesn't mean file will be differ.

Comment: Where did you change the url?

Comment: While downloading I had changed in Download Manager on my android phone. Had just copy paste by long press on android. No worry I've downloaded new iso just released  yesterday. I didn't changed url now let me check if it is working and installing successfully.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it I'm getting Executing **'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.

This is a fatal error.** even I had installed Linux Mint Cinnamon successfully previously. Frustrated. Thought new release would not have any error. Sorry

Comment: Did you check the sha256sum, of the new file?

Comment: Is this your first Gnu/Linux install. I do not recommend installing bleeding edge OS on your production system. Test it in a VM / other-machine. Or just install a more conservative / sell hassle OS such as Debian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85862/discussion-between-swapnil-and-ctrl-alt-delor).